# Link structs and functions without header file in C++

Tags: c++, struct, linker

I'm trying to use a shared library written in C++ from other programs. I have done the shared library and I have tested that it works.

The shared library mentioned above has dependencies to other libraries. I have avoided this problem compiling my shared library telling the linker where to find that dependencies, and deploying that shared library with all its dependencies into a folder.

## The problem

Now my problem is the header files. I have a header file to deploy with my shared library, but this header file also includes 3rd-party headers. For example, I have my shared library `A`, with its header file `AH`. `AH` needs to include `BH` and `CH` header files to get their definitions, **and this is what I want to avoid**.

Then, I think the solution could be to use the `extern` keyword on the 3rd-party functions that I need. The problem with this is that I also need the definitions of some `structs` (that are declared in the 3rd-party header files mentioned above). So, **how can I include this struct definitions using the `extern` keyword?** **Is there any better way to do what I want?**

Comment: Does the user of your library need to know about the 3rd party declarations?  Are you ever returning a value of a 3rd-party type?

Comment: No to both questions.

Comment: If you are just using the 3rd-party types internally, using a pimpl may be the way to go.

Comment: If those are definitions that you need for the implementation, but the user doesn't need for using your library, they should not be in a user-facing header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a header file to deploy with my shared library

Why?  Headers are required only at compile time.  You do not need to provide headers along with the library if all you want to do is run programs that use it.

But maybe you do want to provide for building additional programs that use your library.

> but this header file also includes 3rd-party headers. For example, I have my shared library `A`, with its header file `AH`. `AH` needs to include `BH` and `CH` header files to get their definitions, **and this is what I want to avoid**.

You're not making much sense.  If `AH` requires definitions (or maybe you really mean *declarations*) provided by `BH` and `CH` then you have only two options:

1. Ensure that `BH` and `CH` are available, or
2. Provide alternative, compatible versions of the definitions / declarations that `AH` requires.

You describe needing function declarations.  Certainly if you have calls to B and C functions in `AH`, then you need *full* declarations of those functions.  Function declarations are `extern` by default, so no worries there, but it is essential to have full prototypes.  You could copy those from `BH` and `CH` if you wanted, though that's a bit questionable.

You also describe needing `struct` declarations.  Type declarations have no linkage, so `extern` is irrelevant to them; `extern` would matter here only if you were talking about global variables.  You do not need complete declarations of the `structs` if you use only opaque pointers to instances of those structs.  That means never instantiating them directly; never dereferencing them, not even to invoke methods on them; and generally never doing anything that depends on their size or layout.  If your usage -- *including in your own header file `AH`* -- meets those requirements, then instead of complete declarations of the structs in question you can provide your own, incomplete ones:

```
struct b_struct;
```

Of course, since you can't do anything directly with pointers to those, that only makes sense if the pointers to them are provided by functions from libraries B and C, and your own code does nothing with them apart from store them and pass them as function or method arguments.  If you need them in any more substantial capacity, then you do need the full declarations.  Like with the functions, you can copy those.  Even more than with the functions, that's questionable.

More generally, you inquire

> how can I include [...] definitions using the `extern` keyword?

It is essential to understand that `extern` is about *linkage*.  It is primarily concerned with the run-time visibility of functions, methods, and variables.  It relates to compile-time visibility only inasmuch as the compiler and linker implement linkage rules.  Slapping the `extern` keyword on the declaration of a `struct` type does not magically make that type visible to code that does not contain an actual declaration of that type.